# Vue 3 Composition API useRouter() inside onMounted hook

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-composition-api

I want to use `useRoute` inside my component which is called in onMounted hook.
Something like

```
import { checkUserAuth } from '@/common/CheckUserAuth'

onMounted(async () => {
  await checkUserAuth()
})
```

And CheckUserAuth.ts is:

```
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const router = useRouter() // here router is undefined

export const checkUserAuth = async () => {
  const userStore = useUserStore()
  const userApi = new UserApi()
  const token = localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_NAME)

  const router = useRouter() // and here too router is undefined

  if (!token) {
    await router.push({ name: LOGIN_PAGE_ROUTE })

    return
  }

  const userData = await userApi.fetchMasterInfo()
  userStore.setUser(userData)
  await router.push({ name: DASHBOARD_ROUTE })
}
```

I don't understand why the router is indefined everywhere and is it possible to solve this without passing the router as an argument? (i want to make the checkUserAuth function fully encapsulated)

i know i can fix it like

```
const router = useRouter()

onMounted(async () => {
  await checkUserAuth(router)
})

export const checkUserAuth = async (router: Router) => {
  await router.push({ name: DASHBOARD_ROUTE })
}
```

But it's not good solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composables are supposed to be used directly in setup, unless their implementation allows for other usage, this needs to be determined for each case.

Since checkUserAuth uses composables, this makes it a composable either, in case it needs to be used in mounted hook, it needs to return a function that allows this:

```
const useUserAuth = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const userStore = useUserStore()
  const userApi = new UserApi()

  return {
    async check() {...}
  }
}
```

Alternatively, `checkUserAuth` shouldn't use composables. `useUserStore` doesn't have restrictions that are inherent to composable, and `useRouter` can be replaced with an import of router instance.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I understand the essence of the problem, but what if I want to transfer dynamic components? like ```await UserInfrastructure({phone: `${cityCode.value}${phone.value}`,password: password.value,})```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. UserInfrastructure doesn't exist in original question. The content of `check` will be the same as `checkUserAuth`, with the exception of the usage of `useRouter`, etc composables

Comment: in case someone wants to know what a composable is: https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html

Answer (score 2):

The API of useRouter must be called in setup, as mentioned in the official document. You can see this point in https://router.vuejs.org/zh/api/#userouter(zh document mentioned it).
Maybe you can write code like this:

```
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

export const useCheckUserAuth = () => {
  const userStore = useUserStore()
  const router = useRouter()

  returnv aysnc function checkUserAuth() {
    const userApi = new UserApi()
    const token = localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_NAME)
    if (!token) {
      await router.push({ name: LOGIN_PAGE_ROUTE })
  
      return
    }
  
    const userData = await userApi.fetchMasterInfo()
    userStore.setUser(userData)
    await router.push({ name: DASHBOARD_ROUTE })
  }
}
```

And call it in setup:

```
const checkUserAuth = useCheckUserAuth()

onMounted(() => {
  checkUserAuth()
})
```

hope it can help you.